# What does the plus sign mean in robots.txt?

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt

For a site, I want to do a web crawling at the `/telecommandes` path. It's robots.txt:

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: *telecommande++*
```

My questions are:

- What does the plus-sign mean in this case?
- And is it appropriate to crawl the URL `/telecommandes-box-decodeur.html`? with respect to the robots.txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Per the [original robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html)**, `+` has no special meaning in `Disallow` values, and neither has `*`.

So crawling of `/telecommandes-box-decodeur.html` would be allowed.

Disallowed would be, for example, crawling of `/*telecommande++*.html` (literally).

---

If you want to be polite, you could take "proprietary" robots.txt extensions into account, e.g., from Google and other search engines. Many authors might not realize that these aren’t part of the official specification, and expect them to work even for other crawlers.

**Per [Google’s robots.txt documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en)**, the `+` has no special meaning, but `*` has one (it means: any sequence of characters).

So crawling of `/telecommandes-box-decodeur.html` would still be allowed.

Disallowed would be, for example, crawling of `/foo/telecommande++bar.html` (and still also `/*telecommande++*.html`).